# issue with add variable in javascript source

Tags: javascript, variables

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.src = "http://www.example.com/abc/abc.js?timestamp=" + new Date().getTime();
s.id = 'help-wall';
s.data-campaign-id ='6';
document.body.appendChild(s);
}
</script>
```

showing error in  **s.data-campaign-id**.Please help

Comment: @lonesomeday gave you an answer but in the future it please tell us *what* the error is so we don't have to guess

Answer (score 1):

Hyphens are illegal characters in Javascript identifiers, so can't be used with the object dot syntax. You have to use the square bracket syntax instead:

```
s['data-campaign-id'] = '6';
```

---

Alex in the comments makes the very valid point that this won't register as a data attribute, only as a property of the node. If you want it to be an attribute, you'll need `setAttribute`:

```
s.setAttribute('data-campaign-id', '6');
```

You needn't do this with the other properties, because the properties map onto the appropriate attributes. Because you're using a custom attribute it doesn't.

Comment: That looks like a data attribute for a node but the code above just attaches it as a property of the object

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you obviously cannot use dot notation to denote attributes and properties whose names are not valid identifiers.

`data-*` attributes, however, are a special case. In this case, you can quite easily say

```
s.dataset.campaignId = '6';
```

Internally, the dataset property name is mapped between camelCase (`campaignId`) and dasherized form (`data-campaign-id`), in a way that makes it easier to set, just as one sets `s.style.fontSize = "10px";`.

Note that `s.dataset` is not supported in IE<=10, so for that you'll have to fall back to `s.setAttribute('data-campaign-id', ...)`.